# "Link" google workspace with google cloud platform

Tags: google-workspace, google-hangouts

I only started to use GCP this week. I'm trying to do something similar to this tutorial: [Créer une application Google Chat HTTP avec Cloud Functions  |  Google Chat  |  Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/gcf-app?hl=fr)
When I want to configure the Google Chat API I have the message: " The API Google Chat is only available for Google Workspace users. " (selected text in french in the image) and the form to do the configuration is greyed out. Which makes sense. So I created a Google Workspace.

Ok now how do I "link" my Google Cloud account to the workspace if that makes sense. I can't find anything anywhere probably because I'm not wording the question properly but hopefully you understand what I'm trying to do.

How is my google cloud supposed to know that I have workspace and which one it is to communicate with it?